# Block dnsmadeeasy.com due to bad bots?

Tags: htaccess

Should I block dnsmadeeasy.com due to bad bots/sites using their dns service?

Would this be a scenario of throwing the baby out with the bathwater?

Comment: Can you explain more about what these bots are doing and how you would block them?   I'm not sure how you would even go about blocking users of a particular DNS service or why you would think a DNS service is related to bad bots.

Comment: node2.mobiflock.com - Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MJ12bot/v1.4.5; http://www.majestic12.co.uk/bot.php?+)

Comment: And what does that have to do with DNS made easy?

Comment: Knock down the Nameservers supporting beam & the house of cards will fall and all sites connected to it.

Comment: So their website uses  DNS made easy.   You are planning to look at the DNS records of URLs in every user agent string and see if that is what they use?

Comment: Yes.... http://www.ip-tracker.org/#inputiny

Answer (score 1):

Node2.mobiflock.com does use dnsmadeeasy.com for DNS, however, knowing how to write code to make this work in Apache, you cannot block access to your site based upon any DNS server work fast enough to satisfy users. In fact, it would be an unreliable way of blocking anyone. You could be blocking valid accesses as well as invalid accesses.

It is unfortunate, but bots are the way of life. Having said that, do not waste time if you see a bad bot again and come here. Post a question and I will give you the code.

I have node2.mobiflock.com in my database and *how to block code* exists on my site. ;-) However, I will give that to you now. I have two IP addresses for this site.

I am assuming Apache for this.

Resolves to now: 144.76.194.118

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^144\.76\.194\.118$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Previous: 144.76.137.226

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^144\.76\.137\.226$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

IP address block info:

```
AS24940 - Hetzner Online AG
144.76.0.0 - 144.76.255.255

Block: 144.76.0.0/16
Base Address: 144.76.0.0
Broadcast Address: 144.76.255.255
Net Mask: 255.255.0.0
Host Mask: 0.0.255.255
Bits: 16
Size: 65536
2nd Element: 144.76.0.2
```

***This is not a subscriber block so you will not be blocking users.***

You can block the entire IP address block using:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^144\.76\.([0-2]*[0-5]*[0-5]*)\.([0-2]*[0-5]*[0-5]*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

This are valid IP address blocks for majestic12.co.uk though I have seen two other IP address blocks from two years ago. I have not included them here, but can add them if you see accesses from other IP address blocks.

You can block this bot using your robots.txt file. Majestic is a well behaved bot.

```
User-agent: MJ12bot
Disallow: /
```

These are the most recent user agents:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MJ12bot/v1.4.4; http://www.majestic12.co.uk/bot.php?+)
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MJ12bot/v1.4.5; http://www.majestic12.co.uk/bot.php?+)
```

There was one point where Majestic's user agent was used by rogue bots, but that was a long time ago. I have not researched this in my database, but could if necessary.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and code 8)  MJ12bot was already blocked  8)

Comment: Anytime I can help you with things like this, please let me know. I am here everyday and I can do some research and block code rather fast since that is what I do. ;-)